# searching for a specific key in json and finding the previous and next similar keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Similar to brnwdrng's question, I'm looking for a way to search through a JSON-like object and finding what was the last similar key and the next one.
supposing my object's structure is like so:

```
TestObj = {
"Categories": [{
    "Products": [{
        "id": "a01",
        "name": "Pine",
        "description": "Short description of pine."
    },
    {
        "id": "a02",
        "name": "Birch",
        "description": "Short description of birch."
    },
    {
        "id": "a03",
        "name": "Poplar",
        "description": "Short description of poplar."
    }],
    "id": "A",
    "title": "Cheap",
    "description": "Short description of category A."
},
{
    "Product": [{
        "id": "b01",
        "name": "Maple",
        "description": "Short description of maple."
    },
    {
        "id": "b02",
        "name": "Oak",
        "description": "Short description of oak."
    },
    {
        "id": "b03",
        "name": "Bamboo",
        "description": "Short description of bamboo."
    }],
    "id": "B",
    "title": "Moderate",
    "description": "Short description of category B."
}]
```

};

now i want to find a title with name "oak" after i find that i also want to find the last title before "oak" which in this case is "maple" and next title which is "bamboo".

i would be thankful if anyone can point me to the right direction or give me a pseudocode for it.

Thanks

Comment: This is quite easily doable if you iterate over all products in a category with a for loop. Did you try that?

Comment: i will definitely check it out thanks.

Comment: hey nikhil i am stuck here could you help me on how to do it. I am very new at javascript and i have little to no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
i = 0;
foreach obj in TestObj
   if obj.title = Oak,
      last_title = TestObj[i].title;
      next_title = TestObj[i+2].title;
      i++;
endfor
```

Comment: I will try that in my code and will let you know if it produces the result that i want

Comment: since i am very new to this could you help me with an actual code rather than pseudocode i tried couple of times but doesnot work well and also if you could tell me how can i read data from an external jason file names master.js which has all the json data stored.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a quick code.

```
TestObj = {
"Categories": [{
    "Products": [{
        "id": "a01",
        "name": "Pine",
        "description": "Short description of pine."
    },
    {
        "id": "a02",
        "name": "Birch",
        "description": "Short description of birch."
    },
    {
        "id": "a03",
        "name": "Poplar",
        "description": "Short description of poplar."
    }],
    "id": "A",
    "title": "Cheap",
    "description": "Short description of category A."
},
{
    "Products": [{
        "id": "b01",
        "name": "Maple",
        "description": "Short description of maple."
    },
    {
        "id": "b02",
        "name": "Oak",
        "description": "Short description of oak."
    },
    {
        "id": "b03",
        "name": "Bamboo",
        "description": "Short description of bamboo."
    }],
    "id": "B",
    "title": "Moderate",
    "description": "Short description of category B."
}]
};

var oak, beforeOak, afterOak;

for(var i=0;i<TestObj.Categories.length;i++){
    var products = TestObj.Categories[i].Products;
       for(var j=0; j< products.length;j++){
        var product = products[j];

        if(product.name === 'Oak'){
            oak = product;
            beforeOak = products[j-1];
            afterOak = products[j+1];
            break;

        }
    }
    if(oak) break;
}

alert("Oak : "+JSON.stringify(oak));
alert("Before Oak : "+JSON.stringify(beforeOak));
alert("After Oak :" + JSON.stringify(afterOak));
```

See it in action here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ejDk8/4/

It's pretty easy to understand. If you haven't got it yet, JSON is JavaScript's native object structure. So you can access it with a `dot` notation.

[Starter on JSON in JavaScript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29)

**Btw**, Your json is a little inconsistent. The key for array "Products" in the second Category
is "Product" and not "Products". So I took the liberty of correcting it.